# ReactJS setState conflicts with getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to follow the design pattern in https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/issues/26 (see replies by bvaughn) and create ReactJS editable form, that reads data from the server, show then in the form fields, allows the use to edit values and then save those data back in database.

I have some essential code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        invoice: state.invoice,
        invoiceReady: state.invoiceReady,
    };
};

 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.match.params.id !== prevState.id) {
            return update(
                prevState, {
                    ['id']: {$set: nextProps.match.params.id},
                    ['invoiceReady']: {$set: false}
                });
        } else {
            return update(
                prevState, {
                    ['invoice']: {$set: nextProps.invoice},
                    ['invoiceReady']: {$set: nextProps.invoiceReady}
                });
        }
    }

 handleChange(event) {
        const state = update(
            this.state, {
                invoice: {
                    [event.target.id]: {$set: event.target.value}
                }
            }
        );
        this.setState(state);
    }

componentDidMount() {
        this.requestInvoice();
    }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (!this.state.invoiceReady) {
            this.requestInvoice();
        }
    }
```

and my JSX code contains editable fields like:

```
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            id="invoiceDate"
                            value={this.state.invoice.invoiceDate}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
```

So - according to the mentioned pattern I am initiating the request to the server by `requestInvoice`, some other components handle this action and receives and saves the invoice into the Redux store and that is why those data are automatically written into the `props.invoice` variable and I am further writing `props.invoice` into `this.state.invoice` by `getDerivedStateFromProps` for further local processing of the invoice data. During the work with the form the `handleChange` events are raised and with the help of immutability-helper (update function) the updated fields are written into new state and `setState` is called.

My problem is that during the `setState` call the React is calling `getDerivedStateFromProps` and so the `props.invoice` overwrites any changes that are coming from the user and that ar processed into `handleChange:setState` function.

So - **how to solve this problem: the conflict between `setState` and `getDerivedStateFromProps`?**

Several options may be:

- my design can be flawed. E.g. maybe I should not try to move `props.invoice` into `this.state.invoice` (why not?)? But from the other side it would be nice to save invoice into this.state and be sure that all the changes are applied to the `this.state.invoice` during the editing of the invoice.
- mybe I should prevent execution of `getDerivedStateFromProps` during `setState`?

Maybe some other design pattern or code is more suitable for my ReactJS form?

I am using ReactJ 16.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have arrived at the following solution - with the help of `this.state.stateUpdate` variable - and I consider this as the answer to my question (please comment if this is not sound and neat solution, I can accept other answer as well if that works):

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            invoice: state.invoice,
            invoiceReady: state.invoiceReady,
            stateUpdate: false 
        };
    };

     static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
            if (prevState.stateUpdate) {
              return update(
                prevState, {
                    stateUpdate: {$set: false}
                }
              )
            }
            if (nextProps.match.params.id !== prevState.id) {
                return update(
                    prevState, {
                        ['id']: {$set: nextProps.match.params.id},
                        ['invoiceReady']: {$set: false}
                    });
            } else {
                return update(
                    prevState, {
                        ['invoice']: {$set: nextProps.invoice},
                        ['invoiceReady']: {$set: nextProps.invoiceReady}
                    });
            }
        }

     handleChange(event) {
            const state = update(
                this.state, {
                    invoice: {
                        [event.target.id]: {$set: event.target.value}
                    },
                    stateUpdate: {$set: true}
                }
            );
            this.setState(state);
        }

    componentDidMount() {
            this.requestInvoice();
        }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
            if (!this.state.invoiceReady) {
                this.requestInvoice();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are decided to use `react-redux for component state management`, then you should `avoid` to manage the that `component internal state` using `setState` as its controlled by `redux store.`

Otherwise it will causes such issue and lots of if-else you may need to handle it.

considering your scenario,
During `handleChange` instead calling `setState`,better to `dispatch` an `action` to `update the state in redux store` and then via `connect` it will reflect to your component in the same way you calling API.

```
handleChange(event) {
        const stateData = invoice: {
                    [event.target.id]: {$set: event.target.value}
                }; 
        this.props.callDispatch({'UPDATE_SOME_DATA',stateData})
    }
```

Only thing need to take care, make sure `reducers` update only required passed properties data and leave other data intact updated by API `dispatch action` process.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the solution, that I should keep all the state in the Redux store. But currently I don't want to save business object in Redux store, I would like to get it from the store but I would like to keep in the local this.state for further manipulation and I would like to submit my object to the Redux store only when the use completes the work with the object. Entire form of the business object if one React component in whose this.state I would like to keep my object temporarily during user's work with it.