# Is it possible to detect the cause of getDerivedStateFromProps in React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have observed that the `getDerivedStateFromProps` of the React Component is called in at least 2 cases:

1. when the props are changed, e.g. the component imports Redux store data via component's props when the Redux store have received new data from the external API (either as a result from the request initiated by the component or as a push from external event)
2. when the component's `setState` is called, e.g. user can update data in some element of the component and this update is handled by the procedure that calls `setState`.
3. it is also called during the navigation, when props.match.params.... are changed.

So - I would like determine the cause (1. or 2.) of the `getDerivedStateFromProps` and make distinct actions in each case. How it is possible to make such distinction. Maybe this is not possible to do. Or maybe my architecture is flawed if I wish to do this?

*The main problem for me is - how to pass business object from the redux store (to which the `props` of component points to) into `this.state` of some component for further local manipulation?*

My previous attempt is documented in the question [ReactJS setState conflicts with getDerivedStateFromProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703224/reactjs-setstate-conflicts-with-getderivedstatefromprops) in which the more concrete code examples are available.

Comment: When you call `setState` your props should not change, so `getDerivedStateFromProps` should return null, provided that your checks are right. You can't compare `nextProps` with `this.props` since `this` is not available in a static method. As it is right now, your question is too broad, can you narrow down specifically what you're trying to do, and maybe provide some example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this.props is not available in static methode, it is indeed so. I added the reference to my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703224/reactjs-setstate-conflicts-with-getderivedstatefromprops that gives for background and code samples.

Comment: What I gather from your other question is that you keep an object in the redux store and put it on the component state for in place modification. The first thing you could do is returning null from `getDerivedStateFromProps` when you modify the state without touching the store, that ensures that your state is not modified by `getDerivedStateFromProps`. If you're editing your object in place in your component, each modification shouldn't go to the store, instead send the finalized object when it's done. If you'll modify the object on the store on each change, why keep it in the component state?